# Why is not a string like " " or "" considered as empty or NA?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, na, is-empty

Imagine the following data frame:

```r
df <- data.frame("a"=c(1,2,""),"b"=c(" ",4,5))
 
is_empty(df[3,1])
is_empty(df[1,2])
is.na(df[3,1])  
is.na(df[1,2])
```

Why do I get that either `df[3,1]` or `df[1,2]` are not empty or NA?

I know that if any of those was `NA` then the field should contain `NA` explicitly. However, don't `NA` values correspond to missing values?

What am I not getting here? Maybe the definitions of both "empty" and "NA"? If so, what is the definition of `""` or `" "`? Just a string?

Comment: `""` or `" "` is just a string, not missing or `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

According to description of `?rlang::is_empty`

> Is object an empty vector or NULL?

It is not an empty vector nor NULL, but a blank element `''`.  We need `nzchar`

```
!nzchar(df[3,1])
[1] TRUE
```

The first element of 'b' will return `FALSE` with `nzchar` as well as there is a space involved

```
> df$b
[1] " " "4" "5"
> lapply(df, \(x) is.na(x) | !nzchar(x))
$a
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

$b
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

`trimws` can remove the leading/lagging spaces and then `nzchar` can return `TRUE` (negation)

```
> lapply(df, \(x) is.na(x) | !nzchar(trimws(x)))
$a
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

$b
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

---

The way `is_empty` works will be on the entire vector or list element to check if it is NULL or empty

```
> is_empty(numeric(0))
[1] TRUE
> is_empty(integer(0))
[1] TRUE
> is_empty(list())
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So what is your suggestion if I want to find in just one command all the blank elements containing either space or no space?

Comment: @Miguel_s try `sapply(df, \(x) is.na(x) | !nzchar(trimws(x)))` returns matrix of TRUE/FALSE where TRUE are the location for those space/nospace or NA